# How is the phrase 무궁화 꽃이 피었습니다 in Squid Game pronounced causally versus formally?

Tags: pronunciation

I found the pronunciation of 무궁화 꽃이 피었습니다 [written in one article as](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2021/09/29/what-is-the-doll-saying-in-squid-game-red-light-green-light-explored/)

> mugunghwa kkochi piotsseumnida

Google Translate showed it as

> mugunghwa kkoch-i pieossseubnida

Is it pronounced like

> moo goo hwa kor chi pier sam nida

or if pronounce more casually, is it

> moo goo wa gor chi pier sam nida

or in the show when it was pronounced in a kid's voice, it sounded like

> moo goo wa gor chi pei ar sam nida

how is it pronounced formally and casually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one (mugunghwa kkochi piotsseumnida) is the correct pronunciation.
All the others have some inaccuracies in them.

"kk" in "kkochi" is what's called "tensed consonant", which is the hard, unaspirated version of the k sound, a little like the c in "scout". It is not the same as the simple k sound as an English speaker might expect.

"ss" in "piotsseumnida" is similarly pronounced harder than the usual s in English.

Comment: And keep in mind that romanization is not transliteration. The “u” sounds like /oo/, and the “eu” does not sound like /eww/.